# Gradle bintray and oss.sonatype upload: how to inherit common properties for uploaded artifacts

Tags: gradle, snapshot, sonatype, bintray

I use in gradle build `com.jfrog.bintray` plugin to upload release artifacts to Bintray/JCenter, but for snapshots i use https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

For both processes i use the same *pom* configuration, like this:

1) [OSS SONATYPE](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html#metadata-definition-and-upload) for snapshots

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    pom.project {
      name rootProject.name
      url scmProjectUrl
      scm {...}
      licenses {...}
      developers {...}
}}}
```

2) Maven local / Bintray for releases:

```
def pomConfig = {
  licenses {...}
    scm {...}
    developers {...}
}

publishing {
  publications {
    paymentPublication(MavenPublication) {
      // ...
      pom.withXml {
      def root = asNode()
      root.appendNode('description', project.description)
      root.appendNode('name', project.name)
      root.appendNode('url', scmHttpsUrl)

      root.children().last() + pomConfig
}}}
```

The *pomConfig* part is almost the same the same (except *name* and *url*) for MavenLocal/Bintray and snapshots/Sonatype upload.

**How could i reuse *pomConfig* in `uploadArchives->repositories->pom.project` configuration?**